# octopress: how to display HTML based on user path

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress

**TLDR - How do I access the current user path in octopress/jekyll?**

On my Octopress blog, I would like to display an HTML element only when the user is on the root path. The trouble is that `{{page.url}}` returns `/index.html` on the root path, while my root path in `_config.yml` is set to `'/'`.

Thus, this conditional does not work:

```
{% if page.url == site.root %}
  <div class="blurb">
    <p>{{ site.description }}</p>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

When I change the root in `_config.yml` to match `/index.html` it breaks all of the CSS. Why is page.url pointing to `index.html`? There is no `/index.html` in the url of my live website. Is `/index.html` referencing a controller somewhere?

Is there an easy way to access the current user path in Octopress/Jekyll?

For reference - I am pulling the `page.url` variable from a [Jekyll doc](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/). `{{site.root}}` refers to the root value in the `_config.yml` file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by hardcoding '/index.html' into the conditional.

```
{% if page.url == 'index.html' %}
  <div class="blurb">
    <p>{{ site.description }}</p>
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **source/_layouts/default.html**

`{% if page.front_page %} {% include front_page.html %}{% endif %}`

and then add **front_page: true** 
in index.html

```
---
layout: default
navbar: Blog
front_page: true
---
```